# PHP: For each different key value, group together

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have this mysql sample table:

```
+----+---------------+-------+
| id | company       | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 1  | google        | 50    |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 2  | microsoft     | 24    |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 3  | google        | 12    |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 4  | microsoft     | 89    |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 5  | stackoverflow | 45    |
+----+---------------+-------+
```

And **I want to print it as such so that they are grouped by company:**

```
<ul class="google">
  <li>50</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
<ul class="microsoft">
  <li>24</li>
  <li>89</li>
</ul>
<ul class="stackoveflow">
  <li>45</li>
</ul>
```

This is my current code:

```
$resultx = mysql_query();
$temp=0;   
$p = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
   $p[$temp]['id']=$row['id'];
   $p[$temp]['company']=$row['company'];
   $p[$temp]['value']=$row['value'];
   $temp++;
}
foreach ($p as $obj) {
   echo '<ul class="'.$obj["company"].'"><li>'.$obj["value"].'</li></ul>';
};
```

But my code prints all the company together.

EDIT:

**I want to group the company in different UL's.
I would assume that I would have to use another foreach inside my foreach.**

Comment: In your query use `GROUP BY`

Comment: I cannot understand how person with almost 3k rep asks such questions :( you need to put values into array

Comment: @Lashane - maybe the OP is experienced in another field, like jQuery and he's new to PHP.

Comment: Yup, both would be acceptable ways, but the code is anyway confusing. Why to use 2 loops instead one? And Ofir, he wants to list each result as single row, I guess.

Comment: @OfirBaruch it is doesn't matter which language, it is about general programming and understanding how it works, SO overflowed with such questions from persons with 1 rep - I can understand this, but here is...

Comment: This could be done using group_concat(value) and group company so that for each company all the values will be returned as comma seperations and within the loop you need to explode those value and generate the li block with another loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building your array, make the key of the array be the company name or company id. Since I don't see a company id in your query, I will go with name. Now have it be a multidemsional array, with the inner array beging the values.

```
$resultx = mysql_query();
$p = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
   $p[$row['company']]['id']=$row['id'];
   $p[$row['company']]['company']=$row['company'];
   $p[$row['company']]['values'][]=$row['value'];
}
foreach ($p as $obj) {
    echo '<ul class="'.htmlspecialchars($obj["company"]).'">';
    foreach ($obj['values'] as $value) {
        echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
};
```

Comment: Actually I like you answer better than mine, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultx = mysql_query();
$temp=0;   
$companies = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
   $companies[$row['company']][]=$row;
}

foreach ($companies as $company=>$values) {
   echo '<ul class="'.$company.'">';
   foreach($values as $value){
      echo '<li>'.$value["value"].'</li>';
   }
   echo'</ul>';
}
```

There are of course other ways to do it, to make it simple I used 2 different loops.

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to group the rows by the company since there are multiple rows of the same company.

Comment: I want to group the rows to different UL's

Answer (score 0):

Let us begin:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTableName` ORDER BY `company`
```

Then you do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i<sizeOf($p); $i++)
{
 if ($p[$i] == 0 || $p[$i]['company'] != $p[$i-1]['company']) 
  echo '<ul class="'.$obj["company"].'">';
 ecoh '<li>'.$obj["value"].'</li>';
 if ($p[$i] == 0 || $p[$i]['company'] != $p[$i-1]['company']) 
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$companies = array(); 
//One array that will have companies' names as keys
// and the value would be an array of values.

$resultx = mysql_query();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
  $companies[ $row['company'] ][] = $row['value'];
}

foreach ($companies as $company => $values) { //Loop the companies
   echo '<ul class="'.$company.'">';
   foreach($values as $value) //Loop the values of that company
   {
    echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

** Haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will solve your problem

```
$p = array(array());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
   $p[$row['company']][] = $row['value'];
}


foreach ($p as $key => $obj) {
   echo '<ul class="'.$key.'">';

    foreach ($obj as $val) {
        echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }

   echo '</ul>';
};
```